# SQL and PHP Batch Update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have the following table with the following values :

```
                        id   name  farmid   amount    cycleid   totalprice  quantity  month     year
                        1    DAP     1      2400        1         24000      10       DECEMBER  2012
                        2    UREA    1      2500        1         5000        2       DECEMBER  2012
                        3    SENCOR  1      1200        1         2400        2       DECEMBER  2012
                        4    DAP     2      2400        1         2400        1       DECEMBER  2012
                        5    UREA    2      2500        1         2400        1       DECEMBER  2012
                        6    SENCOR  3      2000        2         4000        2       DECEMBER  2012
                        7    DAP     1      3000        2         3000        1       JANUARY   2013
                        8    UREA    2      3000        2         6000        2       JANUARY   2013
                        9    SENCOR  3      3000        2         6000        2       JANUARY   2013
```

I have a problem on formulating the right SQL statement to do a batch update for example Update rows with month of `DECEMBER` year of `2012` and only with farmid `1` NOTE: A farmid row cannot have more than one  cycleid in the same month e.g  in the month of december. Please help to comeup with the right sql statement for the above problem.This is what I tried in code-igniter:

```
     $chemicalarray = array(
            1=>array('name'=>$B41,'farmid'=>$farmname_id,'amount'=>$D41,'cycleid'=>$cycleid,'totalprice'=>$E41,'quantity'=>$C41,'year'=>$E4,'month'=>$E5),
            2=>array('name'=>$B42,'farmid'=>$farmname_id,'amount'=>$D42,'cycleid'=>$cycleid,'totalprice'=>$E42,'quantity'=>$C42,'year'=>$E4,'month'=>$E5),
            3=>array('name'=>$B43,'farmid'=>$farmname_id,'amount'=>$D43,'cycleid'=>$cycleid,'totalprice'=>$E43,'quantity'=>$C43,'year'=>$E4,'month'=>$E5),
            4=>array('name'=>$B44,'farmid'=>$farmname_id,'amount'=>$D44,'cycleid'=>$cycleid,'totalprice'=>$E44,'quantity'=>$C44,'year'=>$E4,'month'=>$E5),
            5=>array('name'=>$B45,'farmid'=>$farmname_id,'amount'=>$D45,'cycleid'=>$cycleid,'totalprice'=>$E45,'quantity'=>$C45,'year'=>$E4,'month'=>$E5),
                              );
                    foreach ($chemicalarray as $key) {
                        $unitsql = "UPDATE chemical SET name = '{$key['name']}', farmid = '{$key['farmid']}' , 
                                        amount = '{$key['amount']}' , cycleid = '{$key['cycleid']}' , 
                                        totalprice = '{$key['totalprice']}', quantity = '{$key['quantity']}' 
                                    WHERE year = '{$key['year']}'
                                        AND month = '{$key['month']}'"; 
                        $q = mysql_query($unitsql); 
                        echo $key['name']; 
                        echo $key['amount']; 
                        if($q==true){ }else{ echo mysql_error(); }
                    }


Output of var_dump is :
array(8) { ["name"]=> string(8) "Round Up" ["farmid"]=> string(1) "1" ["amount"]=> float(1300) ["cycleid"]=> string(1) "1" ["totalprice"]=> float(15600) ["quantity"]=> float(12) ["year"]=> float(2012) ["month"]=> string(8) "DECEMBER" } Done11array(8) { ["name"]=> string(7) "Krismat" ["farmid"]=> string(1) "1" ["amount"]=> float(1500) ["cycleid"]=> string(1) "1" ["totalprice"]=> float(15000) ["quantity"]=> float(10) ["year"]=> float(2012) ["month"]=> string(8) "DECEMBER" } Done11array(8) { ["name"]=> string(3) "DAP" ["farmid"]=> string(1) "1" ["amount"]=> float(2500) ["cycleid"]=> string(1) "1" ["totalprice"]=> float(75000) ["quantity"]=> float(30) ["year"]=> float(2012) ["month"]=> string(8) "DECEMBER" } Done11array(8) { ["name"]=> string(4) "Urea" ["farmid"]=> string(1) "1" ["amount"]=> float(2000) ["cycleid"]=> string(1) "1" ["totalprice"]=> float(50000) ["quantity"]=> float(25) ["year"]=> float(2012) ["month"]=> string(8) "DECEMBER" } Done11array(8) { ["name"]=> string(9) "Dual Gold" ["farmid"]=> string(1) "1" ["amount"]=> float(2500) ["cycleid"]=> string(1) "1" ["totalprice"]=> float(75000) ["quantity"]=> float(30) ["year"]=> float(2012) ["month"]=> string(8) "DECEMBER" }
```

Comment: What did you try? Where is your SQL?

Comment: This is what I tried in code-igniter:                             foreach ($chemicalarray as $key) {$unitsql = "UPDATE chemical SET name = '{$key['name']}', farmid = '{$key['farmid']}' , amount = '{$key['amount']}' , cycleid = '{$key['cycleid']}' , totalprice = '{$key['totalprice']}', quantity = '{$key['quantity']}' WHERE year = '{$key['year']}' AND month = '{$key['month']}'";
  $q = mysql_query($unitsql);
  echo $key['name'];
  echo $key['amount'];
  if($q==true){
}else{
echo mysql_error();
}
}

Comment: Please edit your original question with that info so that it can be presented properly. What error or unexpected behavior are you getting?

Comment: I only saves the first value of the array in all the rows of the array and ignores the other values that are supposed to update the other rows

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

You are just updating the same exact rows over an over again for each month-year combination. If you need to limit the updates to only certain `year`-`month`-`farmid` combinations, then you need to add `farmid` in your WHERE clause.

Comment: I tried it and still didn't work. It's only updating the rows with only the last values of the loop. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what `$chemicalarray` holds, you might want to add a var_dump of that array to your question.

Comment: I have just edited the code again and included the contents of $chemicalarray

Comment: All of the value in your array have teh same exact variable for year-month-farmid, so you are just doing updates on these same set of rows of the database with each pass,  thus everything gets updated to the last set of values. It looks to me like so should also add 'name' as a WHERE condition perhaps. Through it is really odd that you would be building arrays which would update every filed like this. If name, farmid, month, and year, are static and the other fields are the ones being updated, then the is no need to even put the static fields in the array.

Comment: So should I remove them and try again?

Comment: You need to have an understanding of the fields that you are actually changing and the fields you can use to uniquely identify each record so as to make the updates only to that specific record.  It doesn't seem clear to me that you have that clarified yet.